# How to Get Custom data from json array

Tags: android, json

I'm creating an app which contains A category Activity, the data is showing using JSON.
In this, I sent the id string to another Activity using Intent 
then I want its shows only that data which contains cat_id =id (which I sent to this activity)

This is my category array:--

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Udemy Courses"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Hindi movies"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Hollywood Hindi"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Hollywood English"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Netflix Series"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Tv Series"
  }
]
```

and this is my items array:--

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "first title",
    "description": "description description vdescription description description ",
    "date": "2019-01-08",
    "cat_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "second title",
    "description": "vdescription description vdescription description description ",
    "date": "2019-01-09",
    "cat_id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "title",
    "description": "description description description description ",
    "date": "2019-01-15",
    "cat_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "title",
    "description": "description description description ",
    "date": "2019-01-09",
    "cat_id": 1
  }
]
```

I'M using this code

```
private int CategoryId;



CategoryId = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("id"));





 @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            for (int i=0; i < response.length();i++){
                try {

                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
if (jsonObject.getInt("cat_id")==CategoryId){
                        Item anime = new Item();

                        String Title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                        String Description = jsonObject.getString("description");
                        String Date = jsonObject.getString("date");

                        anime.setTitle(Title);
                        anime.setDescription(Description);
                        anime.setDate(Date);

                        listAnime.add(anime);
                        mProgress.dismiss();








                  } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            setuprecyclerview(listAnime);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

private void setuprecyclerview(List<Category> listAnime) {
    RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,listAnime);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

but this not shows filtered data

For Example:-  when I click on that which has id= 1 (in Category array)

then it shows only that data which has cat_id =1

but this shows me the error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
```

Comment: How is PHP related to this?

Comment: @PatrickQ json is retrieved using PHP I'm not familiar with php

Comment: But where are you having trouble?  In the code above or in some other code not shown?

Comment: You have to specify LayoutManager and adapter in onCreate of an Activity or Fragment

Comment: @sonusharma i suggest you to use https://github.com/google/gson library to parse json objects to java objects

Comment: friends please watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkUNzb2pppA&t=13s

Comment: i want like this app

Answer (score 0):

I've put comments for you

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse (JSONArray response){
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            try {
                jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                //here you have all of the items and you should handle them

                if (jsonObject.getInt("cat_id") == 1) {

                    //change 1 to the number you want
                    //here you have the jsonObject with specific id
                    //for example, I want to get the description from jsonObject

                    String Desc = jsonObject.getString("description);
                }

                Category anime = new Category();

                anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));

                listAnime.add(anime);
                mProgress.dismiss();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        setuprecyclerview(listAnime);

    }
},new Response.ErrorListener()

{
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error){

}
});

requestQueue =Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity .this);
requestQueue.add(request);
}

private void setuprecyclerview(List<Category> listAnime) {
    RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, listAnime);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

Comment: i used this but this code shows me an error      Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"